# iOS Create Dispatch thread dynamically as we call some method?

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, queue, dispatch-async

i m having four arrays want to execute all the array in one method at a single time all at one time for saving execution time of that method can we create different dispatch thread dynamically for executing the method in different queue for fast execution ?

Comment: The overhead of dispatching the tasks on multiple queues is probably greater than simply accessing the arrays sequentially.  You also have a limitation on the number of cores in the device, so there is a limit to how many operations can be completed simultaneously

Comment: @Paulw11 actually i m having multiple array of multiple image with and one method to perform some task for that arrays and its taking lot of time for it...

Comment: You can dispatch the tasks onto a background queue, but there is no way you can guarantee that the tasks will take place simultaneously.  You can use a `dispatch_group` to synchronise the completion of the tasks.  If your tasks are independent  then you may also be able to use `dispatch_apply` see https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationQueues/OperationQueues.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH102-SW20

Comment: yes i can use dispatch_group but the number of array is not fixed so can't guess the number of queue to be declared for executing ..

Comment: It will be inefficient to dispatch each work item to its own queue;  the ability of the device to execute items in parallel is limited by the number of cores.  The work will never be completed any faster than when you perform it on the main queue unless you can pass it to the GPU.  What you can do is dispatch the work on another thread so that you don't block the main queue and provide UI feedback to the user on progress.